# recursion: get object from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have a recursive array like this

```
var data ={
      "isRoot": true,
      "isParent": true,
      "name": "first",
      "id": 1,
      "child": [
        {
          "isRoot": false,
          "id": 2,
          "isParent": false,
          "name": "second",
          "child": [
            {
              "id": 4,
              "child": [],
              "name": "inner",
              "isParent": false,
              "isRoot": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "isRoot": false,
          "id": 3,
          "isParent": true,
          "name": "third",
          "child": []
        }
      ]
    }
```

`child` is nested it may have in any deeper level i want to get the single object from the array that matches an `id`.

For eg if `id=4`  it should return this object

```
    {
      "id": 4,
      "child": [],
      "name": "inner",
      "isParent": false,
      "isRoot": false
    }
```

How can I do that here what I found from the another post

```
function flatten(data) {

    data.forEach(function (element){
        //how can i do the comparison here
        if(element.child.length) {
            flatten(element.child);
        } else {

        }
    });
}

flatten(data.child);
```

But I couldn't get an idea of matching logic does anyone have a solution for this??

Comment: I believe that there is no such thing as *recursive array*. Also, you have an object... therefore, an *object with several levels* might be a better description, do you agree?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado  but  the level of  `child`    is unpredictable

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it go wrong? Post your code here, this isn't a free code writing service. ;-)

Comment: @iambatman Yes, I can see that. I was just trying to make clear that *"recursion"* defines a *function*, not an array.

Comment: @RobG I just looped the array with recursion but stuck with idea of filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a recursive depth first search:

```js
function find(arr, id) {
  for (var e of arr) {
    if (e.id === id) return e;
    var found = find(e.child, id);
    if (found) return found;
  }
}

var data = {
  "isRoot": true,
  "isParent": true,
  "name": "first",
  "id": 1,
  "child": [{
      "isRoot": false,
      "id": 2,
      "isParent": false,
      "name": "second",
      "child": [{
        "id": 4,
        "child": [],
        "name": "inner",
        "isParent": false,
        "isRoot": false
      }]
    },
    {
      "isRoot": false,
      "id": 3,
      "isParent": true,
      "name": "third",
      "child": []
    }
  ]
};

var result = find([data], 4);
console.log(result)
```

Note that I'm passing the top level `data` object in an array for consistency.

Comment: The function body can be reduced to essentially a single line: `for (var e of arr) return e.id === id? e : find(e.child, id)`.

Comment: Its worked one more question suppose I want to modify(like add another key) the matching object in the parent array  ,do i need to get the index and loop again?

Comment: @iambatman I'm not sure what you mean. Once you have a reference to the object you want using this approach, you can modify it as you like.

Comment: suppose  in the matching object I want to change  `isParent` key to true

Comment: Just `result.isParent = true` should work (where `result` is the object you get after you call `find`).

Answer (score 0):

The completed code, It can also find multiple matches:

```js
var data ={
      "isRoot": true,
      "isParent": true,
      "name": "first",
      "id": 1,
      "child": [
        {
          "isRoot": false,
          "id": 2,
          "isParent": false,
          "name": "second",
          "child": [
            {
              "id": 4,
              "child": [],
              "name": "inner",
              "isParent": false,
              "isRoot": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "isRoot": false,
          "id": 3,
          "isParent": true,
          "name": "third",
          "child": []
        }
      ]
    }

function search(data,id) {

    var founds=[];
    data.forEach(function (element){
      
      if(element.id===id)
        founds.push(element);
      
        if(element.child.length) {
            founds=founds.concat(search(element.child,id));
        }
    });
    return founds;
}

console.log(search([data],3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with recursion.You you check if the object have `child` you need to loop through the child array and find the obj with id. Here is my code

```js
var data ={
      "isRoot": true,
      "isParent": true,
      "name": "first",
      "id": 1,
      "child": [
        {
          "isRoot": false,
          "id": 2,
          "isParent": false,
          "name": "second",
          "child": [
            {
              "id": 4,
              "child": [],
              "name": "inner",
              "isParent": false,
              "isRoot": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "isRoot": false,
          "id": 3,
          "isParent": true,
          "name": "third",
          "child": []
        }
      ]
    }

function find(id,obj){
 if(obj.id === id) return obj;
        //if the object has child
 if(obj.child){
                //iterating through child array
  for(let child of obj.child){
                        //call the find function again on eact child
   let childWithId = find(id,child)
                        //if there is some object in child with id
   if(childWithId){
    return childWithId;
   }
  }
 }
}
console.log(find(3,data));
console.log(find(4,data));
console.log(find(1,data));
console.log(find(2,data));
```